# How to build VLC for Android project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libvlc, ndk-build, vlc-android

I am following this wiki: https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ to build libvlc native library for android. So far I have been able to compile and build apk using `compile.sh` which is described on the wiki. Now I am trying to build and run the whole project using android studio. I have selected build variant `dev` to run and build the **apk**. But the android studio produced apk size is smaller than the **apk** produced by using `compile.sh`. After analysing both apks I found that the `libvlc.so` file is missing from the android studio generated **apk**. 
How can I build and run [VLC for Android](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android.git) project using android studio?

Answer (score 0):

I think the libvlc part of VLC-Android can only be built from CLI.

Comment: libvlc part is built without any issue. I am trying to build the included android project with the android stuido.